# perl mocking is there a way to mock $?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, mocking

I am using  [`Test::MockModule`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test%3a%3aMockModule) to test perl module. One of the call require checking status of `$?` to get error code and program checks for it.

How can I mock the result of `$?`

Code under test is like below.

```
my $result = CCUtil::cleartool($cmd);

if ( $? != 0 ) {
    confess  "Stream $stream not found( $result) ";
}
```

The api returns string and sets $? for checking status.

Normal method calls and their return values are changed using something like below

```
my $module = Test::MockModule->new('CCUtil');
$mockModule->mock(cleartool => sub {return 'stream not found'});
```

The method call is now mocked. Not the value  of -- `$?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my $module = Test::MockModule->new('CCUtil');
$mockModule->mock(cleartool => sub { $? = 0x0100; return 'stream not found' });
```